# Using puppeteer queryselector to get only a specific element out of identic elements with same classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-selectors, puppeteer, queryselector

I want to make a website scraper, but the website has multiple elements with same clases, etc.

[image: Blue dots = required info]

I want to collect the information from the blue dots.
Please note that there are multiple `<tr></tr>` with the class odd and even. The example on the photo only shows one of each, but I wanted to point out how similar they are.

So.. Basically the problem I run in is how's going puppeteer to know which information to get if there is another element with the same style and classes?

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors are pretty flexible, you just need to decide which elements do you need.

in your example it can be something like

```
.odd>td:nth-child(1), .odd>td:nth-child(2), .odd>td:nth-child(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with nth-child with range (1-4)

```
.odd td:nth-child(n):nth-child(-n+4){
  // ...
}
```